# ModuleWithProviders / forRoot - use generics as type parameter for a provider

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am wondering why I can't do this:

```
export class TopBannerModule {
  static forRoot<T>(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TopBannerModule,
      providers: [ 
        { provide: AppNavigationServiceToken, useClass: T]
    };
  }
}
```

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

However `useClass` is expecting a type.

Is this possible to utilise generics over a factory here?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll probably have to use arguments instead of generics.

Answer (score 0):

As @edric states, we need a type parameter instead

```
export class TopBannerModule {
  static forRoot(typeOfAppNavigationService: typeof AppNavigationService): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TopBannerModule,
      providers: [ 
        { provide: AppNavigationServiceToken, useClass: typeOfAppNavigationService]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's a good idea to use camelCase for argument/parameters

Comment: And you don't have to use the `typeof` operator - remove it.